# SQL Server Stored Procedure: Filter Table on One-to-Many Relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure that will perform a query against a table that has multiple relationships.

Example main table:

```
dbo.Provider
+----+-----------+------------+
| Id | FirstName |  LastName  |
+----+-----------+------------+
|  1 | Lor       | Blair      |
|  2 | Wanda     | Montgomery |
|  3 | Inez      | Palmer     |
|  4 | Cecilia   | Adkins     |
|  5 | Jessica   | Swanson    |
+----+-----------+------------+
```

Sample one-to-many Relation ships

```
dbo.ProviderSpecialty
+----+----------------+-----------+
| Id |   Specialty    |   Type    |
+----+----------------+-----------+
|  1 | ANESTHESIOLOGY | Primary   |
|  1 | CARDIOLOGY     | Secondary |
|  2 | ANESTHESIOLOGY | Primary   |
|  3 | ANESTHESIOLOGY | Primary   |
|  3 | AMBULANCE      | Secondary |
|  4 | AMBULANCE      | Primary   |
|  5 | CARDIOLOGY     | Primary   |
|  5 | AMBULANCE      | Secondary |
+----+----------------+-----------+

dbo.ProviderAddress
+----+-------+-----------+
| Id |  Zip  |   Type    |
+----+-------+-----------+
|  1 | 11510 | Primary   |
|  2 | 11510 | Primary   |
|  2 | 13090 | Secondary |
|  2 | 96814 | Previous  |
|  3 | 13090 | Primary   |
|  4 | 13090 | Primary   |
|  5 | 96814 | Primary   |
|  5 | 11510 | Secondary |
+----+-------+-----------+
```

I have `dbo.ProviderHealthPlan` and `dbo.ProviderHospital` but they would follow the same approach.

My stored procedure would accept `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Specialty` and `Zip` as parameters.

If the parameter is `null`, then do not filter on that parameter. 
If the parameter has a value, then only display providers where the parameter matches.

Also, I want to show all Specialties and Zips in the result.

For example a search for `Specialty = 'AMBULANCE'` (all others null) would result:

```
+----+-----------+----------+---------------------------+--------------+
| Id | FirstName | LastName | Specialties               | Zips         |
+----+-----------+----------+---------------------------+--------------+
| 3  | Inez      | Palmer   | ANESTHESIOLOGY, AMBULANCE | 13090        |
| 4  | Cecilia   | Adkins   | AMBULANCE                 | 13090        |
| 5  | Jessica   | Swanson  | CARDIOLOGY, AMBULANCE     | 96814, 11510 |
+----+-----------+----------+---------------------------+--------------+
```

A filer on `Specialty = 'AMBULANCE'` and `Zip = '13090'` would return:

```
+----+-----------+----------+---------------------------+--------------+
| Id | FirstName | LastName | Specialties               | Zips         |
+----+-----------+----------+---------------------------+--------------+
| 3  | Inez      | Palmer   | ANESTHESIOLOGY, AMBULANCE | 13090        |
| 4  | Cecilia   | Adkins   | AMBULANCE                 | 13090        |
+----+-----------+----------+---------------------------+--------------+
```

And obviously a filter on first or last name is self-explanatory. I have 4 different one-to-many relationships to filter on, this is just some sample data.

Any help on where to start would be awesome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to read this:

https://sqlwithmanoj.com/2011/12/30/creating-stored-procedures-with-dynamic-search-filter/

Comment: That works great for first and last name, but it doesn't work for the other filters.

Comment: In what way does it not work? Also be aware of parameter sniffing issues in dynamic search filters

Comment: Specialty and zip are not a column on the Provider table. They are a part of a one-to-many relationship. That example only filters columns on one table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter if a value is passed, and not filter if null is passed, 
Then you can build where clauses like this:

```
where [someColumn] = ISNULL(@someVariable, [someColumn])
      and [someOtherCol] = ISNULL(@someOtherVar, [someOtherCol])
```

As far as assembling all of the relationships into a single value, you can use a sub query that reutrns results in the form of XML, and then parse that into a string value. It won't be pretty, but it definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

here something like this should work, I didn't test it but I think it would be easy for you to understand whats happening

```
CREATE PROC Show
@Firstname VARCHAR(50) = NULL
,@LastName VARCHAR(50) = NULL
,@Specialty VARCHAR(50) = NULL
,@zip INT = NULL

AS 
IF (@Firstname IS NOT NULL 
    AND @LastName IS NOT NULL
    AND @Specialty IS NOT NULL 
    AND @zip IS NOT NULL )

    Begin
            SELECT * FROM MainTable M
            JOIN Specialty s ON s.ID = m.id
            JOIN zip z ON z.ID = m.ID
            WHERE m.FIrstname = @Firstname AND m.lastname = @LastName AND s.specialty = @Specialty AND z.zip = @zip


    END 
        ELSE
           BEGIN
               IF( @Firstname IS NOT NULL OR @LastName IS NOT null)
                  Begin
                     SELECT * FROM MainTable M
                     JOIN Specialty s ON s.ID = m.id
                     JOIN zip z ON z.ID = m.ID
                     WHERE (@Firstname IS NULL OR m.Firstname = @Firstname AND @LastName IS NULL OR m.Lastname = @LastName)
                  END 
                     ELSE 
                             BEGIN
                               SELECT * FROM MainTable M
                               JOIN Specialty s ON s.ID = m.id
                               JOIN zip z ON z.ID = m.ID
                               WHERE( @Specialty IS NULL or s.specialty = @Specialty AND @zip IS NULL OR zip = @zip )
                             END
           END
```

Comment: In the real SP I have to filter on Specialty, Health Plan, Hospital, City, and Zip, so the if statement would get crazy.

Comment: well if you have that many filters I would definitely go with dynamic Search in Proc, google it, its a little complicated to write but it works,
Or even better you can create a whole dynamic sql procedure that would only execute the query with the search filter that is being past in. Sounds like a fun procedure to do.